# Pitest targetClasses doesn't retrieve path by ${tests}

Tags: ant, pitest

I don't understand what is happening here. I made a property (test) that has path value as ${currentdirectory.@{targetClasses}} (which stores value of "org.apache.commons.lang3") when I try to give targetClasses its value i use ${test} but it gives me error at $ in property. Does Pitest not allow values to be retrieved.

[image: Code]

Error:

[image: Error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the name from "currentdirectory.@{targetClasses}" to "tests". Now it works in targetTests with "${tests}.*"